# K8s API request with kubeclient ruby gem returns bad-request (400)

Tags: ruby, kubernetes

I'm making a K8s API request with [`kubeclient` ruby gem](https://github.com/abonas/kubeclient) and it returns bad-request (400)

```
ruby: 2.5.0
k8s client version: 1.13.4
k8s server version: 1.14.5
kubeclient: 4.4.0
```

My code:

```rb
require 'kubeclient'
require 'json'
require 'open3'

content = File.open("nginx.yaml").read

p suffix_name = File.extname("nginx.yaml")

case suffix_name
when '.yaml' then
    hash = YAML.safe_load(content)
    p "yaml content is:#{hash}"
when '.json' then
    hash = JSON.parse(content)
    p "json content is:#{hash}"
end

hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} is: #{value}"
    if key == "kind"
    @kind = value.to_s.downcase
    end
end

config = Kubeclient::Config.read("rancher_kube_config.kubeconfig")

kubeconfig_text = File.read("rancher_kube_config.kubeconfig")
config_context = Kubeclient::Config.new(YAML.safe_load(kubeconfig_text), nil)
@config = config_context.instance_eval { @kcfg }
config = @config
deployment = Kubeclient::Resource.new(hash)
cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
ssl_options = {
    cert_store: cert_store,
    verify_ssl: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
}
context = config_context.context
auth_options = {
        bearer_token: context.auth_options[:bearer_token]
}
client = Kubeclient::Client.new('https://{my_host}/k8s/clusters/c-h4mdn/api', auth_options: auth_options, ssl_options: ssl_options)

begin
  @create_entity = client.send("create_#{@kind}", deployment)
rescue Kubeclient::HttpError => e
    p e
    @error_code = e.error_code
    @message = e.message
end

if @create_entity.nil?
    p "false"
else
    p "success"
end
```

The contents of `config.kubeconfig`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: "k8s"
  cluster:
    server: "https://MY_HOST/k8s/clusters/c-h4mdn"
    certificate-authority-data: ...
- name: "k8s-k8smaster"
  cluster:
    server: "https://MY_HOST:6443"
    certificate-authority-data: ...

users:
- name: "user-8lhbv"
  user:
    token: my_token

contexts:
- name: "k8s"
  context:
    user: "user-8lhbv"
    cluster: "k8s"
- name: "k8s-k8smaster"
  context:
    user: "user-8lhbv"
    cluster: "k8s-k8smaster"

current-context: "k8s"
```

The contents of `nginx.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-test2
  labels:
     app: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
     containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
     restartPolicy: Always
```

The error I'm getting is this, and I think it maybe the `apiVersion` is wrong:

```
#<Kubeclient::HttpError: HTTP status code 400, Pod in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Pod: no kind "Pod" is registered for version "clusters/v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:29" for POST https://MY_HOST/k8s/clusters/c-h4mdn/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if kubeclient gem supports server addresses with paths (`MY_HOST/k8s/clusters/c-h4mdn/api/v1` instead of `MY_HOST/api/v1`). k8s-client gem does (disclaimer: am one of the authors)

Comment: @Kimmo Lehto Thank you for your answer, I can actually GET the results when I use the GET method to request the same path, but the POST method doesn't work